# Purging Cloudflare cache with an API call in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cloudflare

I'm looking to purge Cloudflare's cache through its [API](https://api.cloudflare.com/). More specially, the [purge all files](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-all-files) command.

However, I keep running into the *"Invalid Content-Type header, valid values are application/json,multipart/form-data"* error message, despite explicitly setting the `Content-Type` header with Node.js' [request](https://github.com/request/request) package.

What am I missing?

---

```
var request = require('request');

gulp.task('cfPurge', function() {

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/myZoneID/purge_cache',
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-Email': 'email',
            'X-Auth-Key': 'myAPIkey',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        form: {
            'purge_everything': true,
        }
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(body);

        if (!error & response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('CF Purge: ', resp.success);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error: ', resp.errors);
            for (var i = 0; i < resp.errors.length; i++)
                console.log('      ', resp.errors[i]);

            console.log('Message: ', resp.messages);
            console.log('Result: ', resp.result);
        }
    }

    return request.post(options, callback);
});
```

---

Output:

```
Error:  [ { code: 6003,
    message: 'Invalid request headers',
    error_chain: [ [Object] ] } ]
       { code: 6003,
  message: 'Invalid request headers',
  error_chain:
   [ { code: 6105,
       message: 'Invalid Content-Type header, valid values are application/json,multipart/form-data' } ] }
Message:  []
Result:  null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-all-files) for the cloudfare API, you need to send an HTTP DELETE request and not an HTTP POST request:

[image]

Modify the line...

```
return request.post(options, callback);
```

...with:

```
return request.del(options, callback);
```

Also, this is not a form. You need to put the JSON in the body of the data. So, replace the block...

```
form: {
    'purge_everything': true,
}
```

...with:

```
body: JSON.stringify({'purge_everything': true})
```

Comment: Thanks Nehal for your answer, spot on! Much appreciate taking the time to do this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you doing this because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudbleed ?

Comment: No, I'm doing this because the [gulp-cloudflare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cloudflare/) plugin uses an older version of the API which gives me occasional errors when purging.